# AdMob interstitial to open 2 times

Tags: java, android, admob

I have two codes for Interstitial one for you to open apps, and second for when to close the application when the problem is the first code to open 2 times my husband pote give someone a code for the site onStop (exit app)

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupActionBar();
        setupDrawer(savedInstanceState);

        // init analytics tracker
        ((WebViewAppApplication) getApplication()).getTracker();

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-Code");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("Cod")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Code for closing apps

```
@Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-Code");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("Cod")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is your problem i dont get you

Comment: ads twice to open when starting apps

Comment: its because its being called it twice. re-read the docs, call the interstitial from a natural breakpoint sir, there a tons of post like these on here search for them

Comment: public void onStop code to put it because I want you to close apps to show ads. That's where I reason dubplicat InAs because dubplicat when I start my apps to open twice if you know someone opens an account afel of ads when you stop apps